# Pass data from service to controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Following is my Service code -

```
myApp.service('loginServiceChk', function(){
    this.getInfo = {};
    this.chkLogin = function($http,$location,$window){
        $http.get('/users/chklogin')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {             
                if (data.code!="200"){
                    this.getInfo = {};
                    $window.location.href='/#/users/login';
                }else{
                    this.getInfo = data.usersession;    
                }
            }); 
    };
});
```

My controller code -

```
myApp.controller('userDash',function($scope,$http,$location,loginServiceChk,$window){
    loginServiceChk.chkLogin($http,$location,$window);
    console.log(loginService.getInfo);
    $scope.userLogout = function() {        
        $http.get('/users/logout').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.logout=="200"){
                merInfo = {} ;
                $window.location.href='/#/userss/login';
            }   
        })
    };
});
```

However I am always getting an empty object in the console ( `console.log(loginService.getInfo);` ) . Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

I am expecting session data in  the `this.getInfo`.

**EDIT**

If I am using `.then` then it is going in the `if` ie `if (data.code!="200"){` here.

Comment: chkLogin is asynchronous. When you log loginService.getInfo, it hasn't completed yet, so its blank.  You should return a promise object from your chkLogin function.

Comment: Since `chkLogin` is asynchronous call, `getInfo` is not yet populated by the time you are trying to access it.

Comment: @dfsq I am looking this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q but can you please help me to fit this in my scenario as I haven't used promise mefore

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the promise.

Use this in your controller:

```
loginServiceChk.chkLogin($http,$location,$window).then(function() {
    console.log(loginService.getInfo);
});
```

And add `return` to your service:

```
this.chkLogin = function($http,$location,$window){
    return $http.get('/users/chklogin')
        .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {             
            if (data.code!="200"){
                this.getInfo = {};
                $window.location.href='/#/users/login';
            }else{
                this.getInfo = data.usersession;    
            }
        }); 
};
```

Comment: should call then() - its more verbose, but it allows for chaining promises.

Comment: Absolutely, I missed that one

Comment: @PatrickReck This code making my page refresh everytime ..somekind of recursion